# Can you combine socket.io emit features?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I was trying to send coordinate data for a game by using the broadcast modifier and volatile modifier at the same time. Is that able to be done?

```
socket.broadcast.volatile.emit('coords', x, y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  All the `socket.broadcast` and `socket.volatile` properties do is execute a getter than sets the appropriate flag and then returns the `socket` object to allow you to chain them.  Here's [the code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L87) for creating those getters:

```
var flags = [
  'json',
  'volatile',
  'broadcast',
  'local'
];

flags.forEach(function(flag){
  Object.defineProperty(Socket.prototype, flag, {
    get: function() {
      this.flags[flag] = true;
      return this;
    }
  });
});
```

Then, when you call `.emit()` all the flags are passed on to the adapter that does the actual sending as you can see [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L170).  So, the adapter gets the `emit()` and gets the flags (both broadcast and volatile) to do accordingly.

Note that the main feature of volatile is if that a message is not queued if the client connection is not currently available (client is polling or client has lost the connection and may be reconnecting).